# MySQL, CROSS JOIN and unknown column

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote mysql query which use subquery. I can't understand why mysql shows me 'Unknown column 'T.TICKETID' in 'where clause'' in subquery. For MSSQL it works without problem.

```
SELECT @PERIODTYPE := 'Y';


SELECT
  @PERIODTYPE,
  CASE 
    WHEN @PERIODTYPE = 'W' THEN DATE_FORMAT(R.DATENEW,'%u')
    WHEN @PERIODTYPE = 'M' THEN DATE_FORMAT(R.DATENEW,'%Y-%m')
    WHEN @PERIODTYPE = 'Y' THEN DATE_FORMAT(R.DATENEW,'%Y')
    ELSE DATE_FORMAT(R.DATENEW,'%Y-%m-%d') 
  END `Period`,
  DATE_FORMAT(MIN(R.DATENEW),'%Y-%m-%d') min_date,
  DATE_FORMAT(MAX(R.DATENEW),'%Y-%m-%d') max_date,
  COUNT(*) Transactions,
  SUM(SQ.`Sold Units`)  `Sold Units`,
  FORMAT(MAX(P.TOTAL), 2) `Largest Order`, 
  FORMAT(SUM(P.TOTAL), 2) `Total $ Sold`,
  FORMAT(SUM(TXL.AMOUNT), 2) `Total Tax $ Collected`
FROM RECEIPTS R INNER JOIN TAXLINES TXL ON R.ID = TXL.RECEIPT
                INNER JOIN TAXES TX ON TXL.TAXID = TX.ID 
                INNER JOIN TAXCATEGORIES TXC ON TX.CATEGORY = TXC.ID 
                INNER JOIN PAYMENTS P ON P.RECEIPT = R.ID
                INNER JOIN TICKETS T ON R.ID = T.ID  
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(TL.UNITS) 'Sold Units' FROM TICKETLINES TL WHERE T.TICKETID = TL.TICKET)  SQ
GROUP BY CASE 
    WHEN @PERIODTYPE = 'W' THEN DATE_FORMAT(R.DATENEW,'%u')
    WHEN @PERIODTYPE = 'M' THEN DATE_FORMAT(R.DATENEW,'%Y-%m')
    WHEN @PERIODTYPE = 'Y' THEN DATE_FORMAT(R.DATENEW,'%Y')
    ELSE DATE_FORMAT(R.DATENEW,'%Y-%m-%d')
  END
ORDER BY R.DATENEW
```

### Update 1

I replaced table name (TICKETS) instead of alias (T). I got error. Please, see the screenshot. [image]

```
SELECT @PERIODTYPE := 'D';


SELECT
  @PERIODTYPE,
  CASE 
    WHEN @PERIODTYPE = 'W' THEN DATE_FORMAT(R.DATENEW,'%u')
    WHEN @PERIODTYPE = 'M' THEN DATE_FORMAT(R.DATENEW,'%Y-%m')
    WHEN @PERIODTYPE = 'Y' THEN DATE_FORMAT(R.DATENEW,'%Y')
    ELSE DATE_FORMAT(R.DATENEW,'%Y-%m-%d') 
  END `Period`,
  DATE_FORMAT(MIN(R.DATENEW),'%Y-%m-%d') min_date,
  DATE_FORMAT(MAX(R.DATENEW),'%Y-%m-%d') max_date,
  COUNT(*) Transactions,
  FORMAT(SUM(IFNULL(SQ.`Sold Units`,0)),2)  `Sold Units`,
  FORMAT(MAX(P.TOTAL), 2) `Largest Order`, 
  FORMAT(SUM(P.TOTAL), 2) `Total $ Sold`,
  FORMAT(SUM(TXL.AMOUNT), 2) `Total Tax $ Collected`
FROM RECEIPTS R INNER JOIN TAXLINES TXL ON R.ID = TXL.RECEIPT
                INNER JOIN TAXES TX ON TXL.TAXID = TX.ID 
                INNER JOIN TAXCATEGORIES TXC ON TX.CATEGORY = TXC.ID 
                INNER JOIN PAYMENTS P ON P.RECEIPT = R.ID
                INNER JOIN TICKETS ON R.ID = TICKETS.ID 
--                LEFT JOIN (SELECT TL.TICKET, SUM(TL.UNITS) 'Sold Units' FROM TICKETLINES TL  GROUP BY TL.TICKET)  SQ ON T.ID = SQ.TICKET
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(TL.UNITS) 'Sold Units' FROM TICKETLINES TL WHERE  TICKETS.ID = SQ.TICKET)  SQ 

GROUP BY CASE 
    WHEN @PERIODTYPE = 'W' THEN DATE_FORMAT(R.DATENEW,'%u')
    WHEN @PERIODTYPE = 'M' THEN DATE_FORMAT(R.DATENEW,'%Y-%m')
    WHEN @PERIODTYPE = 'Y' THEN DATE_FORMAT(R.DATENEW,'%Y')
    ELSE DATE_FORMAT(R.DATENEW,'%Y-%m-%d')
  END
ORDER BY R.DATENEW
```

Comment: Which version of MSSQL are you using?

Comment: Ok, so I've deleted my answer.

Comment: I just compare possibilities MSSQL & MySQL.

Comment: I think  you can 't use a table alias of an "upper select " in a subquery .. the alias must be at the same level .. subelect is not a JOIN

Comment: How to fix this issues?

Comment: I think you need to replace the CROSS JOIN with `INNER JOIN (SELECT TICKET, SUM(UNITS) AS 'Sold Units' FROM TICKETLINES GROUP BY TICKET) SQ ON SQ.TICKET = T.TICKETID`

Comment: @AndyNichols your's solution works but very slowly. How can I increase of performance of query?

Comment: @YuriyTigiev, I've no idea. How to improve performance will depend on how large each table is and what indexes you have on each. Whatever tool you use to run your query should be able to show you the plan. For example, in MySQL Workbench you can choose "Explain Current Statement" under the Query menu.

Comment: You can also find out whether it's that join causing the problem by commenting it out (and the relevant line in SELECT) and seeing how much of a difference that makes.

Comment: @scaisEdge  whyyyyy???? Why it works in tsql and not works in the mysql :(

Comment: I have posted an answer .. i hope the suggestions are possible for your code ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query don't work in mysql beacuse mysql  can't use an alias declared ad an upper level respect the subquery ..

in your subquery in Cross Join

```
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(TL.UNITS) 'Sold Units' 
         FROM TICKETLINES TL WHERE T.TICKETID = TL.TICKET)  SQ
```

You use T.TICKETID

The alias T

```
  INNER JOIN TICKETS T ON R.ID = T.ID
```

Is declare in a place not "accessible" by the scope of the subquery ..

Then if is possible i suggest you of build a subquery that non refer to T alias .. Try (if is possible ) building an equivalent subquery wihout alias

Comment: I also used name of table instead alias. Result was same. I think It's mysql limitation.

Comment: if you can please post the query without the alis so i can evaluate

Comment: No ...not in comment  ...in this case you should update/edit your question adding the new code  ..eventually with a title Update 1